# WooCommerce: remove block style.css when deregister/dequeue fails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to remove the WooCommerce block styles from the frontend.
This file here:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/build/style.css?ver=4.0.0
```

I tried two different ways which both fail:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array', 1000 );
```

And this function:

```
function disable_scripts_styles() {
    
    wp_dequeue_style('wc-bundle-style');
    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_scripts_styles', 1000);
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Or do I need to use a different approach?

I just saw, that the `style.css` is loaded in the footer. Could that be a problem? I could remove every other style in the head with the function above.

Edit: I found a way to remove the CSS based on the URL of the file:

```
wp_deregister_style('wc-block-style', get_home_url().'/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/build/style.css', array(), null, true);
```

I'm not sure if that is a valid solution. What if the file structure changes?
Isn't there any other/better way?

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, **[This is a link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69339081/15040627)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that will do that magic

```html
/** Disable WooCommerce  Block Styles */
function disable_woocommerce_block_styles()
{
    wp_dequeue_style('wc-blocks-style');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_woocommerce_block_styles');
```

To check it you need to login out or use incognito mode. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In September of 2023 with WooCommerce 8< this worked for me:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/418033